# How jQuery in an array can be searched based on multiple values?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

How jQuery in an array can be searched based on multiple values?
For example, I search by color and os.
Thank

> var products = [
>
> {"id":"1","title":"Apple iPhone 4","os":"ios","color":"red"}
>
> ,{"id":"2","title":"Blac80 Bold","os":"other","color":"blue"}
>
> ,{"id":"12","title":"Black 0","os":"other","color":"red"}
>
> ,{"id":"26","title":"HTC s","os":"android","color":"blue"}
>
> ,{"id":"50","title":"HTC HD7","os":"android","color":"red"}
>
> ,{"id":"21","title":"HTC z","os":"android","color":"blue"}
>
> ,{"id":"11","title":"HTC ion","os":"android","color":"red"}
>
> ,{"id":"3","title":"HTC W","os":"android","color":"blue"}
>
> ,{"id":"6","title":"Motorola","os":"ios","color":"blue"}
>
> ,{"id":"14","title":"Motorola DEFY","os":"ios","color":"red"}
>
> ,{"id":"15","title":"Nokia C7","os":"ios","color":"blue"}
>
> ,{"id":"60","title":"Nokia N8","os":"ios","color":"red"}
>
> ,{"id":"70","title":"Nokia X6","os":"ios","color":"blue"} 
>   ];

Comment: did you even try searching for this? If so please show your code attempts, otherwise that's what you should be doing first before asking here

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find object by id in array of javascript objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-array-of-javascript-objects)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this..**

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var products = [
{"id":"1","title":"Apple iPhone 4","os":"ios","color":"red"}

,{"id":"2","title":"Blac80 Bold","os":"other","color":"blue"}

,{"id":"12","title":"Black 0","os":"other","color":"red"}

,{"id":"26","title":"HTC s","os":"android","color":"blue"}

,{"id":"50","title":"HTC HD7","os":"android","color":"red"}

,{"id":"21","title":"HTC z","os":"android","color":"blue"}

,{"id":"11","title":"HTC ion","os":"android","color":"red"}

,{"id":"3","title":"HTC W","os":"android","color":"blue"}

,{"id":"6","title":"Motorola","os":"ios","color":"blue"}

,{"id":"14","title":"Motorola DEFY","os":"ios","color":"red"}

,{"id":"15","title":"Nokia C7","os":"ios","color":"blue"}

,{"id":"60","title":"Nokia N8","os":"ios","color":"red"}

,{"id":"70","title":"Nokia X6","os":"ios","color":"blue"} ];

$.each(products, function(i, v) {
        if (v.color == "blue" || v.os == "ios") {
            alert(v.title);
            return;
        }
    });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This link is a project
[This link is a project](https://www.transferbigfiles.com/0d8678bd-05b1-4a48-98bc-ac53767c0634/-br17aOg-wowmBQ_H2JVBA2)
I thank check

Comment: @sadegh What i do for you?

Comment: I want to do a search on the checkbox os and color  ?

Comment: Update your html form

Comment: [The download link](https://www.transferbigfiles.com/0d8678bd-05b1-4a48-98bc-ac53767c0634/-br17aOg-wowmBQ_H2JVBA2)thank

Comment: ya i download file and what i do for you?